# Equivalent binary quadratic forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, quadratic-forms

Given $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ we know that it is not necessarily equivalent to $f(-x,y)$ even if they represent the same numbers.

For example our textbook says that $x^2+xy+2y^2$ is equivalent to $x^2-xy+2y^2$, but $3x^2+xy+4y^2$ is not equivalent to $3x^2-xy+4y^2$. How can I see this?

Actually I thought $f(x,y)$ and $f(-x,y)$ cannot be equivalent, since the transformation has determinant $-1$.

I hope someone can clarify.

Comment: "even they are representing the same numbers": what does this mean ?

Comment: This is standard language from the theory of binary quadratic forms.  The "numbers represented" by a form are the outputs obtained by plugging in all possible pairs of integers for $x$ and $y$.  Since $f(x,y) = f(-(-x),y)$, the sets of outputs of $f(x,y)$ and $f(-x,y)$ are identical.  Forms $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equivalent if $f(ax+by, cx+dy) = g(x,y)$ for some integer matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ of determinant $1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You can find the definition of equivalence of quadratic forms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Definitions).

Answer (score 3):

The point is that acting by the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

or its negative is not the only way to move from the form $f(x,y)$ to the form $f(-x,y)$.

You can check by hand that acting on the form $f(x,y) = x^2 + xy + 2y^2$ by the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

produces the desired form $f(-x,y) = x^2 - xy + 2y^2$, and this matrix has determinant $1$.

Proving that no matrix of determinant 1 will carry $3x^2 + xy + 4y^2$ to $3x^2 - xy + 4y^2$ is much harder.  The easiest way is to learn about reduction of forms and then see that these two forms are in different equivalence classes by reducing them and seeing that you get different reduced forms.

(It can be shown that in a class, either every form $f(x,y)$ has the property that it is equivalent to $f(-x,y)$ or no form does.  Later, when you learn about composition of forms, you discover Gauss's seminal result that the primitive classes of forms of discriminant $d$ form a group. The operation of going from $f(x,y)$ to $f(-x,y)$ is inversion in this group, so the classes of forms with $f(x,y)$ equivalent to $f(-x,y)$ are precisely the classes of order dividing $2$ in the class group.)

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer! One question: I already know about reduction theory, so I would like to understand how to show that the last two forms are no equivalent. What do you mean with "different cycles"? Actually I can try to reduce both quadratic forms and see what I will get. If the reduced forms are equal, then the two forms are equivalent. If the reduced forms are distinct, then they are not, correct?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'm used to working with forms of positive discriminant, where the reduction theory is more complicated. I'll edit my response.

Comment: I know how to calculate all the reduced forms of a certain discriminant $d$. Lets say there are two reduced forms of the above discriminant. How can I decide which of them belongs to which of the given quadratic forms $3x^2+xy+4y^2$ and $3x^2-xy+4y^2$?